# Splitting column to array losing leading zeroes

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Haven't used VBA in over a decade. I found some code for splitting a column of data into x number of rows for the indicated range. But I can't seem to find how to keep the leading zeros in the output array.

Column A contains for example:

| A |
| --- |
| 0123456789 |
| 0034453425 |
| 0122346527 |
| 1872635341 |

Output comes back as:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0123456789 | 122346527 |
| 34453425 | 1872635341 |

Any help is appreciated. The inputs are all 10 characters in length, unique barcodes.

Here's the code

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim xCol As Integer
    Dim xArr As Variant

    xTitleId = "Column Split"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    xRow = Application.InputBox("Rows (How many rows max per column) :", xTitleId)
    Set OutRng = Range("C1")
    Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
    xCol = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow

    ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        iRow = i Mod xRow
        iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
        xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
    Next

    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why you are not using Data->Text To Columns, where each column is set to be text? Or Range.TextToColumns method (Excel) ? Or if they are always fixed positions, simple formulae (=MID(A1,1,10), =MID(A1,11,10), ...)

Comment: sneaky trick, add a single quote to the value, excel will treat it as text and leave the leading 0

Comment: Are they considered numbers (to calculate with) or text (like serial numbers)? If the need to be numbers to calculate with don't do and text actions instead set the number format to `0000000000` and they will always have 10 digits (with leading zeros) and you can still calculate with them.

Comment: If you have ms365, try `=WRAPCOLS(A1:A4,2)`. It kept leading zeros intact (assuming you had these numbers formatted as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the output range as text:

```vb
With OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2))
    .NumberFormat = "@" 
    .Value = xArr
End With
```

Comment: If they need to be numbers that you can calculate with you need to use a numeric number format: `.NumberFormat = "0000000000"`.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! Got it going right!